# How to return a variable from a javascript function into html body

Tags: javascript, html

I am still new to javascript, and I am trying to get a function to return a variable using html & javascript.  Basically the function should just return whichever radio button that the user clicks on, although at the moment I don't see anything being returned at all.

The function is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem() {
var chosen = ""
len = document.f1.r1.length
  for (i = 0; i <len; i++) {
    if (document.f1.r1[i].checked) {
chosen = document.f1.r1[i].value
    }
  }
}
return chosen
</script>
```

And then in the html section I have these radio buttons, and my attempt to get the variable "chosen" output to the screen.

```
  <form name = f1><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "ON" onClick=GetSelectedItem()>On
  <Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "OFF" onClick =GetSelectedItem()>Off</form>
  <script type ="text/javascript">document.write(chosen)</script>
```

At the moment nothing seems to be getting returned from the function (although if I output the variable 'chosen' inside the function then it is working correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using return outside function body

Comment: Well first off, using JQuery would be the way to go. JQuery is a javascript library that is really good for doing anything related to the DOM.

Comment: Google hosts the JQuery library. So you could just do the following script tag in HTML and then you are ready to use the API. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Use a validator (such as http://validator.w3.org/ ) there are all sorts of things wrong with that that a machine can point out for you.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend going near jQuery until you have at least a basic understanding of what it is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - really appreciate them and will have a look at jQuery when I'm a little better at javascript :)

Comment: I don't think one should avoid JQuery even if they are new. You may not understand everything that is going on behind the scenes but that will be learned as they continue to use it (that is the point of a useful API no?). But fundamental syntax concepts are required, I would agree to this extent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a little simpler approach.

First, make a few corrections to your HTML, and create a container to display the output:

```
<form name = "f1"> <!-- the "this" in GetSelectedItem(this) is the input -->
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "ON" onClick="GetSelectedItem(this)">On
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "OFF" onClick ="GetSelectedItem(this)">Off
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Then change your script to this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
         // Grab the output eleent
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

       // "el" is the parameter that references the "this" argument that was passed
    function GetSelectedItem(el) {
        output.innerHTML = el.value; // set its content to the value of the "el"
    }
</script>
```

...and place it just inside the closing `</body>` tag.

[***Click here to test a working example.** <sup>(jsFiddle)</sup>*](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xxwa7/)

Answer (score 4):

`document.write` takes a string, and outputs it as part of the HTML. This is **not** a live value that updates when the variable pointing at the string is updated.

For that, you will need to perform [DOM manipulation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/).

Comment: +1 I have a feeling you were down voted for daring to suggest that a person shouldn't use jQuery (at least at first).

Answer (score 2):

Change your JavaScript function to something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem() {
  len = document.f1.r1.length;
  for (i = 0; i <len; i++) {
    if (document.f1.r1[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById('test').textContent = document.f1.r1[i].value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then in the body:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I put in the post. Using JQuery would make your life easy for this kind of task (and many others for the matter). The really nice thing about JQuery is that it often makes your JavaScript syntax much easier then you can learn the nitty gritty details of javascript as you go.
First, add the following script tag into your html page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you have the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)

Then you could rewrite the function like this.

```
    function GetSelectedItem(btnRadio)
    {
        var jqElem = $(btnRadio);
        $('#output').html(jqElem.attr('value')); //attr('<name of attributre'>) gets the value of the selected attribute
    }
```

Your html would look like this

```
    <form name = "f1">
        <input type = "radio" name = "r1" value = "On" onclick="GetSelectedItem(this)">On
        <input type = "radio" name = "r1" value = "Off" onclick ="GetSelectedItem(this)">Off
    </form>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

More or less, the .html() can both get and set the html of the selected element. So we are just simply inserting the value into the div tag.

Comment: Your code won't work as written because you've removed `GetSelectedItem()` from the global context.

Comment: While you're at it, you may want to fix `btnRadio.val()` since it won't work because `btnRadio` is a DOM element.

Comment: If you're plugging jQuery, might as well also note that it'd be better to establish the event handlers outside of the HTML markup too.

Comment: true but it's a little much at that point for someone who knows nothing about JQuery. It also distracts from the question he is really asking. I'm sure if he takes the time to read the tutorials and how tos on JQuery he will learn that bit on his own